# How to check if user input is a 1 or a 2

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to ask the user to enter a number representing difficulty but when I use the `if` statement to check if the difficulty is 1, the code block inside the `if` is never executed although I input `1`.

Same with the answers for the questions.

For example when I run the code and it asks me to enter the difficulty and I enter a 2 or 1000 it still proceeds with the code. Same thing with the answers it just displays `you got it correct` even if I enter 1945 for the first question which is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

code:

```
int difficulty;
cout << "Please choose a difficulty: 1 for easy 2 for medium 3 for hard: ";
cin >> difficulty;

if (difficulty = '1')
{
    ifstream file_("questions.txt");
    if (file_.is_open())
    {
        std::getline(file_, ques1);
        cout << ques1 << std::endl;
        int answr1;
        cout << "Enter 1 for: 1945, Enter 2 for: 1914 \n";
        cin >> answr1;
        if (answr1 = '1914')
        {
            cout << "Well done you got it correct! \n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect answer was 1914! \n";
        }

        std::getline(file_, ques2);
        cout << ques2 << std::endl;
        int answr2;
        cout << "Enter 1 for: 1937, Enter 2 for: 1939 \n";
        cin >> answr2;
        if (answr2 = '1939')
        {
            cout << "Well done you got it correct! \n";

        }
        else {
            cout << "The answer was 1939 \n";
        }

        std::getline(file_, ques3);
        cout << ques3 << std::endl;
        int answr3;
        cout << "Enter 1 for: George Bush, Enter 2 for: George Washington \n";
        cin >> answr3;
        if (answr3 = '2')
        {
            cout << "Well done you got it correct! \n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "It was George Washington \n";
        }

        std::getline(file_, ques4);
        cout << ques4 << std::endl;
        int answr4;
        cout << "Enter 1 for: 14, Enter 2 for: 11 \n";
        cin >> answr4;
        if (answr3 = '11')
        {
            cout << "Well done you got it correct! \n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "It was 11 \n";
        }

        std::getline(file_, ques5);
        cout << ques5 << std::endl;
        int answr5;
        cout << "Enter 1 for: She was born with 6 figners , Enter 2 for: 6 toes \n";
        cin >> answr5;
        if (answr3 =' 2')
        {
            cout << "Well done you got it correct! \n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "It was 6 Toes \n";
        }

        file_.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "File is not open\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe change `if (difficulty = '1')` to `if (difficulty == 1)`?

Comment: if (difficulty = '1') ?? Did you get it?

Comment: You say "Enter 2 for: 1914". Shouldn't you be comparing with `2` rather than `'1914'`?

Comment: Can you describe what you expect `if (answr1 = '1914')` to do?   It doesn't compare `answr1` with the value `1914`.

Comment: Simple summary: `'1'` != 1.  Use `"` for multiple text characters, e.g. `"1914"`.  Use `=` for assignment, `==` for comparison.  Prefer to use `std::string` for text (multiple characters).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed here with your if statements.You want user to choose between two options so if they choose anything other than 1 or 2 give them a prompt and expect one of those two answers.See below example:

```
 if (answr1 == "1914")
        {
            cout << "Well done you got it correct! \n";
        }
        else if(answr1 == '1945') {
            cout << "Incorrect answer was 1914! \n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect Input!Plese input 1 or 2 \n";
        }
```

P.S: In C++ `=` operator is for assignment. Use `==` for comparison

Comment: Also note that strings should be used for multiple characters, e.g. `"1914"`, not `'1914'`.

Answer (score 0):

To make an equality comparison use: `==`:

```
if(difficulty==1)
{
    cout << "You selected difficulty 1" << std::endl;
}
```

If you do

```
if(difficulty=1)
{
    cout << "You selected difficulty 1" << std::endl;
}
```

1 is assigned to difficulty. The `if` condition is checked (in such a situation it is checked the variable is not 0) and so is always satisfied.

Comment: What's the difference between the two code fragments?

Comment: Pardon me, there was an error. I edited the question: now it is correct. The difference is in one you use `=` and in the other `==`.

Answer (score 0):

At first (advice!), you are dealing with user input. You should always consider the possibility that user input is not correct!

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
```

If the user typed e. g. 'x', the stream gets into an invalid state and you won't be able to read anything else successfully any more. So after each input, you should check the stream:

```
if(!std::cin)
{
    // print some error message?

    // reset the error state!
    std::cin::clear();
    // skip whatever yet is buffered in the stream
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())
    // now std::cin is ready to use again...
}
```

You could do this in a loop , have further checks on the input and only exit if it is valid... Try to make a function of to avoid code duplication.

```
int difficulty;
std::cin >> difficulty;
if (difficulty = '1')    // << !!!
```

Two errors at once: The single equality sign is not a comparison, but an assignment! So you assign the value of the character '1' (which is not numerically 1!) to the variable `difficulty` – and then check the result of this assignment. As the variable now gets a value different than 0 (zero), the if block will be entered – *always*. For comparison, you need to use:

```
if(difficulty == '1')
//            ^^
```

OK, remains the value: `'1'` is a character literal, not a numeric one. Most likely, you are using a character set that is compatible with [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) on the first 128 characters, and if so, `'1'`
corresponds to the numerical value of 49. Pretty sure this is not what you want... So:

```
if(difficulty == 1)
//               ^ integer literal, numerical value!
```

Alternatively, you could read in a character:

```
char difficulty;         // different type!
std::cin >> difficulty;
if (difficulty = '1')
```

This now would read in a simple character without doing any conversions at all, whereas reading into int converts one *or more(!)* characters into a numerical value. Without conversion, the character input remains as is and you can compare against the character value...

```
 int answr1;
 cin >> answr1;
 if (answr1 = '1914')
```

Same all alike, now, however, you are using an invalid character literal!

You could compare with a string, if at all:

```
 std::string answr1;
 cin >> answr1;
 if (answr1 == "1914")
```

or again as integer just as above (`if(a == 1914)`). On the other hand, though:

```
std::cout << "Enter 1 for: 1945, Enter 2 for: 1914 \n";
```

Above comparison would require the user not to enter `2` for correct answer, but `1914`! So you'd rather compare against the options:

```
 if(answr1 == 2)
```

Finally, some further advice: You are coupling the questions from a text file with statically linked response options in the code. Well, your text file is in vain this way...

You might try to drag the answers from the file, too. Further advantage: You can avoid duplicate code by usage of a loop, and you can organize your questions for different difficulties in different files. Your code then could look similar to this piece code:

```
std::ifstream file;
std::cin >> difficulty;
switch(difficulty)
{
case 1:
    file.open("question_1.txt");
    break;
case 2:
case 3:
     // ...
     break;
default:
    // invalid input! -> appropriate handling
    break;
}

std::string text;
for(;;)
{
    std::getline(file, text);
    // the question text:
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    // the answer options:
    std::getline(file, text);
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
    // read the correct answer:        
    std::getline(file, text);
    int answer; // parse appropriately from text!
    // read the text for output, if users answer was not correct!
    std::getline(file, text);

    // now read in user input and compare against correct answer...
}
```

File format now is quite obvious: For every question four lines, content as described above. You might invent up something more elaborate or even use XML, but for now, it should suffice...

Well, you still need to correctly determine the end of the file and exit the loop if reached, leaving this as an exercise to you...